# Show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Given probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$, a sequence of random variables$ \left\lbrace  X_n \right\rbrace$ and $X \in L^1(\Omega,F,P)$.

If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability and $E[\left| X_n  \right| ] \rightarrow E[\left| X  \right| ]$ as n $\rightarrow \infty$, show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$.

---

I want to show that $E[\left| X_n  \right| ] \rightarrow E[\left| X  \right| ]$ implies uniformly integrable to prove the $L^1$ convergence. But how do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Fatou lemma:
\begin{align}
|X_n - X| &= X_n+ X −2\min(X,X_n)
\\
\limsup E|X_n - X| &= 2E[X] - 2\liminf E[\min(X,X_n)] 
\\&\le 2E[X] - 2 E[\liminf \min(X,X_n)] 
\\&=  2E[X] -  2E[X]  = 0
\end{align}

Comment: Where did you use convergence in probability?

Comment: in $\liminf \min (X_n,X) = X$. because if $X_n \to X$ in probability, you can extract a subsequence converging a.s.